# Swift UIButton and IBAction crashing in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, swift, ibaction

I am creating a reachability alert that I wrote in Swift and is being called in the app that is written originally in objective C. I have all my bridged-header-.h  setup correctly. The problem is happening when I click on a UIButton created in Swift and an IBAction that is also written in swift. below is the error and code. Is there a way to prevent this crash?

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNotificationQueue buttonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae602d0'**

```
//  NetworkErrorView.swift


import Foundation
import UIKit



@objc class NetworkErrorView: NSObject {

    var xCoordinate:CGFloat = 0
    var yCoordinate: CGFloat = 0
    var width: CGFloat = 0
    var height: CGFloat = 0
    var reTryButton = UIButton()


func renderAlertView() -> UIView  {

    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Connection Failed"
    alert.message = "Your device is not connected to the Internet. Please try again later."
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()
    return alert

    }


func renderReTryButton() -> UIView {

    var buttonImage = UIImage(named: "Btn-Try-Again@2x.png")
    reTryButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTapped:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    reTryButton.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    reTryButton.frame = CGRect(x: 18, y: 470, width: 290, height: 30)
    println("stopes here")
    return reTryButton

    }


   @IBAction func buttonTapped (sender: AnyObject!) {

    let alertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Connection Failed"
    alertView.message = "Your device is not connected to the Internet. Please try again later."
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.show()

    }

func render() -> UIView {

    var networkErrorView = UIView()

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;

    let screenHeight = screenSize.height;

if screenHeight == 480 {

    xCoordinate = 0

    yCoordinate = 74

    width = 320

    height = 361

    var imgNoConnection = UIImage(named: "Noconnectionz.png")
    networkErrorView = UIImageView(image: imgNoConnection)

    }

else if screenHeight == 568 {

    xCoordinate = 0

    yCoordinate = 74

    width = 320

    height = 443

    var imgNoConnection = UIImage(named: "Noconnection@2x.png")
    networkErrorView = UIImageView(image: imgNoConnection)

    }

    return networkErrorView

}
```

}

here is where I am calling it in Objective C

```
Swift *connectivity = [[Swift alloc]init];
bool swiftConnected = [connectivity reachability];

if (!swiftConnected)  {
    NetworkErrorView *networkErrorView = [[NetworkErrorView alloc]init];
    [networkErrorView renderAlertView];
     UIView *subView = [networkErrorView render];
    [super.view addSubview: subView];
    [super.view addSubview:[networkErrorView renderReTryButton]];

    } 
   }
```

Comment: Try anyObject without unwrapping it?
@IBAction func buttonTapped (sender: AnyObject)

Comment: I've tried that and I've tried making it a sender from UIButton as well.

Comment: When ever I take out this line of code : reTryButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTapped:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) I can click the button without a crash, but I obviously need the action assigned to the button. I am wondering  if other people are having this issue. I am using xcode6 beta 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
[networkErrorView renderAlertView];
 UIView *subView = [networkErrorView render];
```

Your function `renderAlertView` has no side effects, that is, all it does is create a UIView and give it back to you. But even though it has no side effects, you are still calling it without assigning it to something.

I'm not quite sure what `render` does (please show us the code for that!), but my guess is that it doesn't return anything, it just renders `networkErrorView`, but you are assigning it as a `UIView`. So, I'm thinking you want something more like this:

```
UIView *subView = [networkErrorView renderAlertView];
[subView render];
```

Comment: I added the code for render to my question. When there is no internet connection the render function creates a UIView with an overlay image and a UIAlert telling the user there is no internet, the button that is also rendered in the view is a retry button to check again for connection. The problem is in the button it's self. When I add the code to run the IBAction Function the app crashes and gives me the error message.

Comment: @ArmorKing1212 Hmmm... I don't know what the problem is then. All I can tell you is that `[NSNotificationQueue buttonTapped]` means that an instance of `NSNotificationQueue` is getting the method `buttonTapped` somehow, which should be a button instead. Can you show us the full crash log?